# How to compile YOLOv3 with opencv?

Tags: opencv, yolo, darknet

I want to user YOLOv3 for object detection in videos on macOS 10.14.1
I hence installed opencv 4.0.1

```
brew install opencv
```

Changed the line

```
OPENCV=0
```

to

```
OPENCV=1
```

in the darknet makefile

I then specified the pkgconfig link

```
 export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

and recompiled

```
make

g++ -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DOPENCV -c ./src/image_opencv.cpp -o obj/image_opencv.o
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
./src/image_opencv.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
```

Should I understand YOLOv3 works with openCV 2.0 only?

Comment: You can use Yolo directly with the `dnn` module without downloading/making Darknet at all, if you want. Check [this tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-object-detection-using-yolov3-with-opencv-python-c/) and [that tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/).

Answer (score 4):

Using OpenCV 4, we need to modify the Makefile:

Modify pkg-config name from opencv to opencv4:

```
LDFLAGS+= `pkg-config --libs opencv4` -lstdc++
COMMON+= `pkg-config --cflags opencv4`
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out, YOLOv3 indeed needs opencv 2.0

you can find the version using

```
brew search opencv
```

and then

```
brew install opencv@2
```

the information will be displayed on how to update your links

YOLOV3 then compiles and runs as a charm.

(I will update the answer if things eventually go south...)

Comment: I'm using more modern darknet fork from AlexeyAB: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

Comment: No. Just use opencv 3.xx and you will be fine

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by installing the opencv using following commands

```
> pip install opencv-python==4.1.1.26
> 
> sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```

Reference : https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/1886#issuecomment-548454746